# Equivalent of PHP __invoke() in VB.net

Tags: php, vb.net

Is there an equivalent of PHP __invoke() in VB.net?

I would call an object as method, like this:

```
Public Class Testclass

    Public Function MagicFunction( ByVal obj as object ) as Boolean
        Trace.WriteLine( obj.toString() )
    End Function
End Class
```

An the call look like this

```
Dim myTestObj = new Testclass()
myTestobj(1) 'should output: 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You'll have to call the function myTestobj.Magicfunction(1)